# Clear data in android using coding

Tags: android

I want to clear data through coding for my application. Right now I am Clearing Data from Settings->Applications->Manage Application->My Application->**Clear Data**.

But I want to do it through coding. 
Please help me if any one have answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Context's [getFilesDir](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getFilesDir%28%29) method to get the directory, and then delete all directory and data as explained [here](http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0483.html).

Answer (score 0):

Using MByD's code to delete a dir, delete the folder /data/app/my.app.name ;-)

Answer (score 0):

If the data is "Internal" to the application, it generally can't be cleared from any other app. I did read that you want to clear data of *your* app *through coding* but it wasn't clear whether you want to clear data from the same app.

You need to change the same application's code and instruct it to delete the data. But, if you're clearing from the same application you might want to specify which database table or file, for instance, you want to delete instead of just clearing all the data.

You'll find application data here: /data/data/packagename.appname/

Use this to delete the application files: [deletefiles()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#deleteFile%28java.lang.String%29)