# How can I clear localstorage when I update apps from playstore?

Tags: android, angularjs, ionic-framework

I have made one Android mobile application using Angular and Ionic. I already have uploaded it in the playstore which is running in 1.0 version. Now I am going to update my app in playstore.

When the user updates the app the localstorage should be cleaned. Can any one help me out to move forward?

I want to clear localstorage for my app each time I install.

Comment: Check out the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6912541/clear-data-in-android-using-coding

Answer (score 5):

1. Add version-code variable to your app.
2. Every time your app starts,  check local storage if there is saved the same versions code. If it matches do nothing otherwise perform clean up and save new code to localstorage.

Edit:
Somewhere at the beginning of your app:

```
 /*your currnt app version, 
  you should manually update it here*/
  var version = "200";
  /*get version code stored in localstorage*/
  var savedAppVersion = localStorage.getItem("version");
  /*if there is one check if it is the same*/
  if (savedAppVersion && savedAppVersion === version) {
    // do nothing
  } else {
    /*clear all local storage*/
    localStorage.clear();
    /*save new code to ls*/
    localStorage.setItem("version", version);
  }
```

Edit 2:
you can use plugin for cordova to get app version automatically:
[ngCordova](http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/appVersion/)

So you can use $cordovaAppVersio service:

```
$cordovaAppVersion.getVersionNumber().then(function (version) {
        // use version here
      });
  }, false);
```

Comment: how can i do this . dont mistake me i am new to this.pls give me sample code

Comment: how can i get version details from playstore.

Comment: great.
I store in my settings a flag to tell if we want clean or not

Answer (score 0):

A quick reference from [Android Documentation](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html).

```
public class FeedReaderDbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    // If you change the database schema, you must increment the database version.
    public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "FeedReader.db";

    public FeedReaderDbHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL(SQL_CREATE_ENTRIES);
    }
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // This database is only a cache for online data, so its upgrade policy is
        // to simply to discard the data and start over
        db.execSQL(SQL_DELETE_ENTRIES);
        onCreate(db);
    }
    public void onDowngrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        onUpgrade(db, oldVersion, newVersion);
    }
}
```

By increasing the `DATABASE_VERSION` by +1 eg. `DATABASE_VERSION = 2` the `onUpgrade()` method will be called and the SQL query for delete will invoked then followed by the creation of table.

For [Ionic](http://redwanhilali.com/ionic-sqlite/) reference:

```
angular.module('starter', ['ionic', 'starter.controllers', 'starter.services', 'ngCordova'])
//inject $crodovaSQLite
.run(function($ionicPlatform, $cordovaSQLite, $rootScope) {
$ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
// Hide the accessory bar by default (remove this to show the accessory bar above the keyboard
// for form inputs)
if (window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
}
if (window.StatusBar) {
// org.apache.cordova.statusbar required
StatusBar.styleLightContent();
}

  $rootScope.db = $cordovaSQLite.openDB("my.db");
  $cordovaSQLite.execute(db, "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS joke");
  $cordovaSQLite.execute(db, "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS joke(id integer primary key, joke text)");

});
})
```

The idea is similar to the Native implementation (Drop and Recreate Table).

If you submit this app to the playstore, all the user receiving the update will also get the cleanup instantly.

Comment: i am using ionic angular .